# Trying to declare a cursor, but I'm getting hit with end of file! (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently learning Oracle SQL and I am on cursors right now. I know it's a small problem, and probably easy to solve, but my declaration statement is pulling an end of file error. (PLS-00103)

Here is the statement:

`declare cursor CustCursor is select * from Customers where cust_email is null;`

Any help would be appreciated, it might also be worth knowing that I followed the Sams Teach Yourself SQL Book and am still getting these problems.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`DECLARE` can't exist *alone in the Universe* - it is part of a PL/SQL block which also requires at least *dummy* `BEGIN-END` part of it.

This is what you have:

```
SQL> declare cursor CustCursor is select * from Customers where cust_email is null;
  2  /
declare cursor CustCursor is select * from Customers where cust_email is null;
                                                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 78:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:
begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
exists prior
```

This is what you **should** have:

```
SQL> declare cursor CustCursor is select * from Customers where cust_email is null;
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or, as Ed Stevens says, to put everything where it belongs (although, the result will be just the same):

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor CustCursor is select * from Customers where cust_email is null;
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: just to make it more clear what-is-what, I'd drop the 'cursor is ...' down a line, leaving the DECLARE on a line of its own.  Makes it more clear (hopefully!) that the CURSOR is a lexical element of its own . . .

Comment: My intention was to show that the "original" statement is, actually, correct - if put into the right *environment*, @EdS. But yes, I agree with you so I posted a *prettier* example as well. Thank you for the comment!